# Expected value - law of unconscious statician

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value

If I have X~Uniform(1, 8.7) and Y|X = x~Exp(x)

And we need to find E[XY], is this valid? And are there simpler ways to get the answer?

What I did was use both the probability density functions and plug x for the lambda
$$ \int_1^{8.7}\int_{0}^{\infty} xy \frac{1}{8.7-1}xe^{-xy} dydx = 1 $$

.. is that right?

Comment: Do you mean that the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X=x$ is exponenciális with parameter $x$?

Comment: If the answer is yes then your integral is the expectation of $XY$. But the result is not necessarily $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
E(XY)&=E(E(XY|X))\\
&=E(XE(Y|X))\\
&=E(X \times \frac1X)\\&=1
\end{align}